# rails3 can't iterate from NilClass on model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date, methods, model, null

I'm defining the following Model method:

```
   def live
       deb = start_date||= 100.years.ago # if the start date is nil, it's live
       fin = end_date||=100.years.from_now # if the end date is nil, it's live
       Date.today.between?(deb, fin)
   end
```

if start_date and end_date are filled, the method returns the right value (true or false)
if they're nil, it raises the error "can't iterate from NilClass"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a different approach?

```
def live
  deb = self.start_date? ? start_date : 100.years.ago
  fin = self.end_date? ? end_date : 100.years.from_now
  Date.today.between?(deb.to_date, fin.to_date)
end
```